# Missing parameter code_challenge_method

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'am learning oauth 2.0 and used keycloak as authorization server.whenever I'am sending following request:-

```
http://localhost:7070/auth/realms/developer/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=tcs&response_type=code&scope=openid profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback&state=zxczczxc232
```

I got error given below:-

```
http://localhost:8080/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=Missing+parameter%3A+code_challenge_method&state=zxczczxc232
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

keycloak has PKCE enabled and because of that, you as a client must send a code_challenge as part of the initial authentication request.

What you need to do is to:

1. Generate a random value (code_verifier)
2. Calculate the hash of that value (code_challenge)
3. Send the code_challenge in your initial auth request
4. Send the code_verifier when you later ask for the tokens

Like this picture shows below:

[image]

Comment: how to disable PKCE?

Comment: To disable PKCE , see the documentation here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#advanced-settings

But, today you should learn and use PKCE, as it is best practice to use... and its not that complicated.

Comment: This is actually a good answer. This is extremely easy to set up and you shouldn't disable PKCE. It's just sending a hashed secret over to verify the returned handshake.

Answer (score 3):

I have counter same problem and my solution is:
Step to fix is:
Clients task -> Choose your client -> Advance Setting -> Go to selection box: Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method -> Make it empty(not select any thing)
And you don't need to provide parameter code_challenge_method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).